# Expected index range from 0 in fortran run time error

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

In my application, I have the following in my code. I am using `mpi_f08` in that specific routine to use the function `MPI_F_SYNC_REG` for safe synchronisation. It seems using `mpi_f08` is triggering the problem.

```
 use mpi_f08, only: MPI_F_SYNC_REG
 do I = 1, noblocks
 ncell = geom(I)% ncell
 allocate(buf(ncell,6))
 call MPI_IBCAST(buf,root,ncell*6, request, mpi_comm_world, mopier)
 call mpi_wait(request, mpier)
 ptr = buf(:,6)
 deallocate(buf)
 enddo
```

When running with openmpi and gfortran I get the following runtime error:

> Fortran runtime error: Index '6' of dimension 2 of array 'buf'
> outside of expected range (0:5)

I am running with gcc 10.1.0 and openmpi 4.1.0. Recreating this problem is tough, I am seeking an advice or hints, if any of way might have came across such problem before. What could this be? Because clearly I am explicitly allocating 6 elements on the 2nd dimension, and I don't see why gfortran suddenly switches to a 0 based indexing

Comment: Most likely you are writing in the memory you are not supposed to write to and you have a typical heap corruption.Enable all debugging flags in your compiler and check that you are calling all MPI procedures exactly as you should.

Comment: I have these: `-g -fbacktrace -fno-second-underscore -cpp -std=legacy
                -fbounds-check -fcheck-array-temporaries -fcheck=all -fno-range-check -Wno-tabs -Wsurprising -ffixed-line-length-none -ffree-line-length-512 -fdec -O0 -c` . Am I missing others?

Comment: Are you doing `Use mpi_f08`? There's a horrible bug in (I think) gfortran which can remap the indices causing havoc. But `Use mpi_f08` is definitely the thing that triggered it when I cam across it

Comment: Is this relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63824065/lbound-of-an-array-changes-after-call-to-mpi-gatherv-when-using-mpi-f08-module

Comment: YES I AM, Omg. Okay thanks I will try to workaround using that

Comment: OMG indeed. I'll mark as duplicate, but it would be good if you can edit your question to include the `Use mpi_f08` bit

Comment: Can confirm now that by removing `use mpi_f08`, this problem is solved.