# The 'use mpi_f08' statement causes Fortran MPI programs to crash on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: fortran, mpi, mpich, ubuntu-22.04

I am using Ubuntu for development of Fortran (2008+) programs with MPI.  Things were pretty settled on earlier Ubuntu versions, but I am experiencing some difficulties to compile and run Fortran/MPI on Ubuntu 22.04, which I installed on a new PC very recently.

I first installed OpenMPI, but it wouldn't compile my programs at all, complaining that it can't find some include files related to `mpi_f08`.  (I am sorry, but I can't recall the exact message and I uninstalled the OpenMPI since).

I had better luck with MPICH though.  It can compile my programs, but crashes during execution as soon as the first communication between processors should take place.  A minimum example which demonstrates the issue is given below:

```
subroutine global_sum_real(phi_old)
use mpi_f08
implicit none
real    :: phi_old
real    :: phi_new
integer :: error
call mpi_allreduce(phi_old,         & ! send buffer
                   phi_new,         & ! recv buffer
                   1,               & ! length
                   mpi_real,        & ! datatype
                   mpi_sum,         & ! operation
                   mpi_comm_world,  & ! communicator
                   error)
phi_old = phi_new
end subroutine

program global_sum_mpi
use mpi_f08
implicit none
real    :: suml
integer :: error
call mpi_init(error)
suml = 1.0
call global_sum_real(suml)
print *, suml
call mpi_finalize(error)
end program
```

I hope it is clear what is happening above.  The main program (`global_sum_mpi`) initializes MPI and calls one subroutine (`global_sum_real`) which is essentially an interface to `MPI_Allreduce`. Very simple.

If I compile it with mpifort (it is an: mpifort for MPICH version 4.0 ... gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)) and try to run it in parallel, it crashes with the error:

Internal Error: Invalid type in descriptor

in the line which calls `MPI_Allreduce`.  The funny thing is that if I change the modules I used for MPI from:

```
use mpi_f08
```

to the plain:

```
use mpi
```

Everything works as expected.  This is not a route I would like to take because I believe that `mpi_f08` is more up to date with later Fortran standards and I also need the `mpi_f08` for better compatibility with external PETSc libraries.

Any ideas on why the `use mpi_f08` is causing problems on the new Ubuntu installation?

Kind regards

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, probably something fishy between the compiler and Fortran 2008 TS extensions. As a workaround, you can use an array of one `real` instead of a scalar as the send buffer for `MPI_Allreduce()`.

Comment: a simpler workaround is to use an intermediate variable `phi_tmp` and pass it to `MPI_Allreduce()`

Comment: Thanks a lot @GillesGouaillardet, but I am ending up with quite a lot of workarounds.  It seems that whenever I call an MPI function (for MPICH/Ubuntu 22.04 combination) sending an argument, I have to introduce a little array or a temporary variable.  What do you think about mid- to long-terms, will this issue be fixed for Fortran 2008 extensions, or will I have to live with workarounds?

Comment: I'd ditch MPICH - from what you are saying it just looks totally broken on your box. Why didn't Openmpi work? On my mint box it works with just a simple apt get. Did you try to compile openmpi yourself? And are you compiling mpich yourself? If so in both cases what happens if you just try the packages?

Comment: @IanBush: I switched to MPICH only because OpenMPI didn't work on my box.  No, I didn't try to build it myself, I guess that's the next logical step.  Thanks.

Comment: When you looked at OpenMPI did you install the libopenmpi-dev package? That's the one that gives the "header files" and it works on the box I currently am on, which runs Ubuntu 20.04.5. The module seems to be in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/mpi_f08.mod

Comment: Note also there is another particularly nasty bug in the gfortran/mpich combination which is described in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63824065/lbound-of-an-array-changes-after-call-to-mpi-gatherv-when-using-mpi-f08-module" . As far as I am concerned this is a complete show-stopper.

Comment: well, the bug you mentionned has been fixed in upstream GCC. In this case, there is something wrong with Ubuntu. The reproducer (from my answer) works if built with `-static-libgfortran`. I also rebuilt vanilla GCC 11.2 and GCC 11.2 with Ubuntu patches (at least I did my best to mimic that) and was unable to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The root cause is a bug in `gfortran` provided by Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy).

Here is a sample program that crashes

```
module mymod
        implicit none
        interface bar
        subroutine bar_f08ts (a) bind(C, name="sync")
        implicit none
        type(*), dimension(..) :: a
        end subroutine
        end interface
end module

module pub
        implicit none

        interface sub
        subroutine pub_f08ts(a)
        implicit none
        type (*), dimension(..) :: a
        end subroutine
        end interface
end module

        subroutine pub_f08ts(a)
        use mymod
        implicit none
        type (*), dimension(..) :: a
        call bar(a)
        end subroutine

subroutine bugsub(a)
        use pub
        implicit none
        real :: a
        call sub(a)
end subroutine

program bug
        implicit none
        real a
        a = 1
        call bugsub(a)
end program
```

```
$ gfortran test.f90
$ ./a.out 
Internal Error: Invalid type in descriptor

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f27b38c2ad0 in ???
#1  0x7f27b38c3649 in ???
#2  0x7f27b38c3e38 in ???
#3  0x7f27b3b058a4 in ???
#4  0x56281847220b in ???
#5  0x5628184721c4 in ???
#6  0x562818472264 in ???
#7  0x5628184722a0 in ???
#8  0x7f27b36a0d8f in __libc_start_call_main
    at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#9  0x7f27b36a0e3f in __libc_start_main_impl
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#10  0x5628184720c4 in ???
#11  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
```

I was unable to reproduce this issue on a redhat box with various `gfortran` version.

The right way to move forward is to report this to Ubuntu and wait for a fix.

Meanwhile, you can either use an other distro, or use Open MPI (that does not use the `CFI_desc_t` stuff, so the `gfortran` bug should not impact you).
I do not understand how to use the ubuntu packages for `openmpi` (some are provided, but unless I missed something, the libraries and header files are not available), but you can build and install from source in your home directory (no need root access).

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

The issue occurs because `gfortran-11` uses `libgfortran` from `gfortran-12`, and then bad interaction happens.

I reported this to the GNU folks at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108056

Comment: The root cause is an incompatibility in `libgfortran`. Ubuntu have `gfortran-11` uses `libgfortran` from `gcc-12`. This makes sense since the version of `libgfortran` is the same between `gcc-11` and `gcc-12` ... except in this case, these are not compatible. I will report it to the GNU folks first to clarify whether this is a bug (e.g. compatibility should have been preserved) or a "packaging" issue (e.g. compatibility is known to be broken and library version should have been bumped).

Comment: Thanks for digging into this and filing the bug.